# count on date between

Tags: mysql, sql

table food

```
"Expire date"food name
"2010-01-01"porato
"2011-01-01"tomamto
"2013-01-01"chips
"2011-01-04"orange
"2017-01-01"banana
```

i wanna use select to get out how much food expire in date between 2010-01-01 to 2013-12-30

so the out should be like

```
2010 1
2011 2
2013 1
```

i try

```
select foodName,ExpireDate 
from food
where ExpireDate between '2010-01-01' and '2013-12-30'
```

but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the results by year, you need aggregation:

```
select year(ExpireDate) as year, count(*)
from food
where ExpireDate between '2010-01-01' and '2013-12-30'
group by year(ExpireDate);
```

Note:  It seems odd that you are skipping the last day or two of `2013` (depending on whether `ExpireDate` has a time component).  More typical logic would be:

```
select year(ExpireDate) as year, count(*)
from food
where ExpireDate >= '2010-01-01' and
      ExpireDate < '2014-01-01'
group by year(ExpireDate);
```